# I want to show the differences on main file itself using CVS?

Tags: linux, unix, cvs

I am planning to show the differecnes on the samefile by using `CVS`.

Say i have one file `a.txt`,it contains two revisions.

```
2.0

3.0
```

i can find differecne using `cvs diff -r 3.0 -r 2.0 a.txt`,but i want to show the changes on `3.0` file only.

That means i want to display the latest file of `a.txt` and mention the changes happend to file ?

Is it possible? Can someone guide me to how to start on this?

Answer (score 1):

`cvs log -N -S -rHEAD a.txt` should give you the log message. If you have't checked out the latest revision, you can use `cvs rlog`

I don't know a way to print the latest revision (as in "cvs cat" or similar) with CVS. You probably have to use `cvs checkout` or convert your repo to a modern version control system (which you should really consider anyway; CVS is really outdated).

Comment: cvs log gives only the comments added and no of lines added and removed,but it will not give what i asked right ?

Comment: In that case, I don't understand what you ask for. What are "changes"? Can you give an example what the output should look like?

Comment: Say i have one file a.txt in cvs.it has 10 lines 'hi' is the line added on  1st april. and next day i removed this first line and added 'bye'.so i try to find out what happened on that file using cvs. if i run cvs diff for two revisions i will get the difference only. but i want to see full file as it is,and show the content of  a.txt file with what happend on the file.say one line removed and one line added...and what removed and what added.All should appear on the same latest file with additional lines which not touched

Comment: something like doing winmerge on prev file and latest file

Comment: Ah. Use `cvs diff -u -N` for this.